# Does my code become old? Max exec time exceeded, after few months of using it again

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I use `stylesheet.xslt` and `paths.xml` to transform some RSS feeds and output them in a new created file `fid.xml`

This code was working properly a few months ago and I decided to upload it again today. However i get a

[22-Nov-2012 20:30:32 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/..../public_html/..../feeder.php on line 20 *( line 20 is where the transformation begins)*

```
<?php

// create an XSLT processor and load the stylesheet as a DOM 
$xproc = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt = new DomDocument;
$xslt->load('feeder/stylesheet.xslt');    // this contains the code from above
$xproc->importStylesheet($xslt);

// your DOM or the source XML 

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom -> load('feeder/paths.xml');

// do the transformation

if ($xml_output = $xproc->transformToXML($dom)) {
  file_put_contents('fid.xml', $xml_output);
} else {
    trigger_error('Oops, XSLT transformation failed!', E_USER_ERROR);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Source file is too big. 30 seconds(default timeout) is not enough. You can increase time by changing php.ini `max_execution_time` to a large number. Or try to optimize your input files to be smaller.

Comment: @E_p ok but how it worked a few months ago?!

Comment: Smaller incoming file(s)

Comment: Or faster server. Maybe the load has increased because of more users/vistors or other heavy scripts, which can snoop processing power away from this script. Maybe a configuration has changed. Maybe an update was installed that performs less well in general or in this specific situation. There are many possibilities, but in general XSLT is slow in PHP, and especially when you've got large and, complex files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLTProcessor transform to xml from a string and not a document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645747/xsltprocessor-transform-to-xml-from-a-string-and-not-a-document)