# XSLTProcessor transform to xml from a string and not a document

Tags: php, xslt

This is my problem: I am trying to use XSLTProcessor to transform xml to html. I have already read about its use, but I have the following problem - the transformToXML(xml_file) function requires the xml_file to be an actual xml file. Is it possible for the transformToXML function to use a string instead of a file? I have tried searching this online but all I get is stuff I have already seen with the use of an xml file. Since I need to use this transformation on a big scale (a big number of different transformations for a lot of users) I can't use a file on the server. Here's my code so maybe you can get a better picture:

```
$productxml=  GetShoppingItem($params);

$file = 'ProductQr.xml';    
file_put_contents($file, $productxml);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('ProductQr.xml');

$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load('XSLTForProduct.xsl');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($XSL);

$html = $xslt->transformToXML( $xml );
return $html;
```

As you can see, here I am getting the $productxml string and writing it into ProductQr.xml so I can later use it here: transformToXML($xml). But there will be a lot of transformations and I can't use one xml file since there are a lot of different products. Ideally I would use:

```
$html = $xslt->transformToXML($productxml);
```

without writing into the xml file, but the transformToXML needs a file and not a string. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loadXML` instead of `load` to parse XML from a string.

Comment: It works. It seems that I have to get better acquainted with DOMDocument and its functions. Thanks a lot.